Crop 2:1 Image from ImagePicker
I have that ImagePicker for choosing an image from the library or taking a new one with the camera. After choosing it, i can edit it, but the frame is fixed as a square. I need 2:1 format though. Is there a way to edit the square or a 3rd party library? Or does anyone have a readyToUse solution?
import SwiftUI

struct ImagePicker: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    @Binding var image: UIImage?
    var sourceType: UIImagePickerController.SourceType

    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIImagePickerController {
        let picker = UIImagePickerController()
        picker.delegate = context.coordinator
        picker.sourceType = sourceType
        picker.allowsEditing = true
        return picker
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIImagePickerController, context: Context) {}

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }

    class Coordinator: NSObject, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
        let parent: ImagePicker

        init(_ parent: ImagePicker) {
            self.parent = parent
        }

        func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
            if let image = info[.editedImage] as? UIImage {
                parent.image = image
            } else if let image = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage {
                parent.image = image
            }

            parent.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
        }
    }
}


You can write your own overlay, Apple's sample app shows you how to do it.
If you are extending an existing UIImagePicker feature, you should consider it. But if you are adding this framework to your app, you should consider that its one of the oldest legacy pieces, and Apple has added newer frameworks for each of the major features this framework provides.
